# Troubleshooting 'member reference base type is not a structure or union' error when testing Libfuzzer with my En class

Tags: data-structures, constructor, reference, structure, union

Error: Member reference base type is not a structure or union

I have a class which has public interfaces to be tested using Libfuzzer LLVM library. The class is

```
Class En {
public:
explicit En(Instance_Specifier const& specifier);
void log_check(Verify verify);

private:
Instance_Specifier overview_instance;
};
```

The Libfuzzer Code I've written is:

```
extern "C" LLVM..(data, data_size)
{
Verify verify(static_cast<uint32_t>(data_size)); //Conversion 
En obj(Instance_Specifier(verify)); 
obj.log_check(verify); //Call log_check 
}
```

Error is: member reference base type En (Instance_Specifier) is not a structure or union.
Expectation: The element verify is successfully passed through the obj created.